# Let $ T(A) = A^t $ be linear transformation with $ \langle A, B \rangle = tr(A^t B) $. Then $ T^* = T $

Tags: linear-algebra

**Theorem**: Let $ V = M_n(\mathbb{R}) $ with inner-product  $ \langle A, B \rangle = tr(A^t B) $. Let $ T: V \to V $ be a linear transformation  defined as  $ A \mapsto A^t $ for all $ A \in M_n(\mathbb{R})  $. Thus $ T^* = T $ ( the conjugate transformation is equal to the transformation ).

**Proof attempt**:
For all $ A,B \in M_n(\mathbb{R}) $ we have that
$ \langle T(A), B \rangle = tr(~(T(A))^t B~ ) = tr( (A^t)^t B ) = tr(AB) = tr(BA) = tr(~(BA)^t ~) = tr(A^t B^t ) = \langle  A,B^t \rangle = \langle A, T(B) \rangle $

( I've used the facts that $ tr(AB) = tr(BA) $ and $ tr(A) = tr(A^t) $ for square matrices ).

Note that $ \langle T(A), B \rangle = \langle A, T^* B \rangle = \langle A, T(B) \rangle  $ so that $ \langle A,T^*(B) - T(B) \rangle = 0 $ for all $ A,B \in M_n(\mathbb{R})  $
[ I got stuck here ]

**Question**: How do I continue from where I've stopped to show that  $ T^* = T $? I have no clue.

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: Let $A = T^*(B) - T(B)$.

Comment: Thanks. now I understand. Since $ A, B $ were arbitrary, I can chose $ A = T^*(B) - T(B)  $ and then $ \langle A, T^*(B) - T(B) \rangle = \langle A, A \rangle = 0 $ hence $ A =0  $, therefore $  T^*(B) - T(B) = 0$ and so $ T^*(B) = T(B) $ and since $ B $ is arbitrary then $ T^* = T $

Comment: @h I'd say that you've already shown what you need to show. By definition, $T^*$ is the transformation $S$ for which $\langle T(A),B \rangle =\langle A, S(B)\rangle$ for all $A,B$. You have shown that this condition holds with $S = T$, so $T = T^*$.

Comment: a 3rd option: write $V$ as a direct sum of symmetric and skew symmetric matrices, with symmetric consisting of rank 1 diagonal matrices and rank two matrices (with zeros on the diagonal) ; skew symmetric matrices being rank 2.  After suitable re-scaling this is an orthonormal basis w/ respect to $\langle, \rangle$ and $T$ acts as the identity on symmetric matrices and $-1$ times the identity on skew matrices.  Hence $T$ is given by a diagonal matrix with 1s and -1s and $T^*$ is given by the transpose (i.e. the same matrix) hence $T=T^*$.  As a bonus this tells you $\det\big(T\big)$.